# How to read SESSION variables with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am having requirement in my project that I need to **READ A SESSION VARIABLE WITH JQUERY** and the session variable is created using PHP. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just like any other PHP variable. AJAX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access session variables directly from jQuery: Sessions run on the server; JavaScript runs on the client.

You'd have to export the variables from PHP to JavaScript, e.g. like so:

```
<script>
SESSION = { 
 "abc": "<?php echo $_SESSION["abc"]; ?>",
 "def": "<?php echo $_SESSION["def"]; ?>",
 "ghi": "<?php echo $_SESSION["ghi"]; ?>",
 };

alert(SESSION.abc);  // will output "abc"

</script>
```

Be careful to export only session variables that are not security relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You cannot read SESSION directly from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either make a server request for the session data, or have the server output the session data as part of a javascript

JavaScript is (usually) run only on the client side, and PHP is run on the server side. You can't directly access session data from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = <? echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method you could use is to input the value from the session variable into a hidden text box, then get Jquery to read from that text box